# Is it possible to know which files are available in a specific web folder with AS2 or AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I would like to build an image gallery in Flash with AS2 or AS3 that detects automatically the number of images available in a specific folder (say a level below the swf file).

The goal is to don't have to config any xml files with the images to show.

Is this possible?

Comment: I believe it's not possible without a server-side technology like php or ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Since Flash is client side technology, this would be a can of worms in terms of security. There are a number ways to enumerate files in a directory using server side technology, wether it be WebDAV or a server side programming language such as PHP. You'd have to decide wether or not any of those may fit your purposes.